# I have ?x string on css and js in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I fix this site speed recommendation with wordpress to remove `query strings from static resources`.

I have some Resources with a `?x54532` at the end of the link including images, js, css...

```
des/css/dashicons.min.css?x54532'
wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?x54532
wp-content/uploads/2017/12/favicon.png?x54532"
```

I have 131 links with this query string: `?x54532`

Please, help me. I have tried a lot of plugins and codes and they didn't help

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Updated code block

Comment: What's so bad about adding a version parameter to static resources? If your web server is configured correctly, it should make no differences to caching and site speed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. May help

```
function _remove_script_version( $src ){
   $parts = explode( '?x', $src );
   return $parts[0];
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
```

Place the code provided at the end of your `wordpress` website active theme `functions.php` file.

But noticed, that the code above remove `query strings` only from `css` and `js` files.